# Enable search functionality in external list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I am able to successfully load data from an external database. There are about 6000 rows in the database. The use case is that the users should be able to toggle a checkbox in one of the columns. The first few rows are user -friendly where in I can edit the row by clicking "Edit Page" and modifying the same. However, for other users, they need to navigate few pages before they find their name on the list. Using the filter option is a possibility but requires scrolling through all of them. I want to implement a search functionality. I watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewoiJFJH9ig, and I could create the JS pages, but I am not sure where I can inject the JS scripts. I looked at ListView.aspx and it looks like Sharepoint does not allow for custom injection ("Only content controls are allowed directly").

Can someone guide me how to add search functionality in Sharepoint 2013 for external lists? I have seen a few blogs but do not provide great detail about the implementation. Are there alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue, here is what worked for me:

1. go to your settings and edit page.
2. add a web part, choose the filters option, from the list filter options choose text filter.
3. right click on the web part the select connections> send filter values to
4. select your external list...from the connection type choose "Get Filter Value From" click configure
5. Choose a column you want to filter by 
   click ok then its done, it should filter by a value you supply

Comment: I am getting error message stating that the filter is not connected. How do I fix it?